# concurrent async_write. is there a wait-free solution?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

`async_write()` is forbidden to be called concurrently from different threads. It sends data by chunks using `async_write_some` and such chunks can be interleaved. So it is up to the user to take care of not calling `async_write()` concurrently.

Is there a nicer solution than this pseudocode?

```
void send(shared_ptr<char> p) {
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_write_mutex);
  async_write(p, handler);
}
```

I do not like the idea to block other threads for a quite long time (there are ~50Mb sends in my application).

May be something like that would work?

```
void handler(const boost::system::error_code& e) {
  if(!e) {
    bool empty = lockfree_pop_front(m_queue);
    if(!empty) {
      shared_ptr<char> p = lockfree_queue_get_first(m_queue);
      async_write(p, handler);
    }
  }
}

void send(shared_ptr<char> p) {
  bool q_was_empty = lockfree_queue_push_back(m_queue, p)
  if(q_was_empty)
    async_write(p, handler);
}
```

I'd prefer to find a ready-to-use cookbook recipe. Dealing with lock-free is not easy, a lot of subtle bugs can appear.

Comment: Assuming the transmission runs as fast as possible, what would be the advantage of interleaving data from several threads? It would not speed up the total transmission rate, and the threads would not finish faster on average.

Comment: the whole buffer passed to async_write() must be sent as a contiguous block. it has some structure. imagine something like http-answer, with the header and the file content. if there are concurrent async_write()s, the structure will be broken.

Comment: From boost docs:

 This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's async_write_some function, and is known as a composed operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations (such as async_write, the stream's async_write_some function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until this operation completes.

Answer (score 4):

> async_write() is forbidden to be
>   called concurrently from different
>   threads

This statement is not quite correct. Applications can freely invoke `async_write` concurrently, as long as they are on different `socket` objects.

> Is there a nicer solution than this
>   pseudocode?
>
> ```
> void send(shared_ptr<char> p) {
>   boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m_write_mutex);
>   async_write(p, handler);
> }
> ```

This likely isn't accomplishing what you intend since `async_write` returns immediately. If you intend the mutex to be locked for the entire duration of the write operation, you will need to keep the `scoped_lock` in scope until the completion handler is invoked.

There are nicer solutions for this problem, the library has built-in support using the concept of a [strand](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html). It fits this scenario nicely.

> A strand is defined as a strictly
>   sequential invocation of event
>   handlers (i.e. no concurrent
>   invocation). Use of strands allows
>   execution of code in a multithreaded
>   program without the need for explicit
>   locking (e.g. using mutexes).

Using an explicit strand here will ensure your handlers are only invoked by a single thread that has invoked `io_service::run()`. With your example, the `m_queue` member would be protected by a strand, ensuring atomic access to the outgoing message queue. After adding an entry to the queue, if the size is 1, it means no outstanding `async_write` operation is in progress and the application can initiate one wrapped through the strand. If the queue size is greater than 1, the application should wait for the `async_write` to complete. In the `async_write` completion handler, pop off an entry from the queue and handle any errors as necessary. If the queue is not empty, the completion handler should initiate another `async_write` from the front of the queue.

This is a much cleaner design that sprinkling mutexes in your classes since it uses the built-in Asio constructs as they are intended. This [other answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7756894/283302) has some code implementing this design.

Comment: are you sure about the `strand`? I believe that the question is how to send non-interleaved packets asynchronously. What I believe and I have the same issue, he has one thread calling `io_service::run()`, and some other thread that wants to write some response.
For example 2 other threads issue `async_write()` on the same `socket` object, order of actual calls to `async_write_some()` is undefined.
Only `strand` guarantee that only completion handlers of this write operations will be serialized,which is the case,because only one thread had called `io_service::run()` anyway.Comments appreciated.

Comment: @DragomirIvanov yes the strand is necessary to ensure access to the outgoing message queue used for serializing calls to `async_write`. I've updated my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

We've solved this problem by having a seperate queue of data to be written held in our socket object.  When the first piece of data to be written is "queued", we start an `async_write()`.  In our `async_write`'s completion handler, we start subsequent `async_write` operations if there is still data to be transmitted.

Comment: This. Using strands as suggested by Sam Miller's answer can ensure that you don't get concurrent access on the send queue, which means no need for mutexes. So this solution will be wait-free as requested if implemented correctly.