# boost::asio async condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

The idea is to be able to replace multithreaded code with boost::asio and a thread pool, on a consumer/producer problem. Currently, each consumer thread waits on a `boost::condition_variable` - when a producer adds something to the queue, it calls `notify_one`/`notify_all` to notify all the consumers. Now what happens when you (potentially) have 1k+ consumers? Threads won't scale!

I decided to use `boost::asio`, but then I ran into the fact that it doesn't have condition variables. And then `async_condition_variable` was born:

```
class async_condition_variable
{
private:
    boost::asio::io_service& service_;
    typedef boost::function<void ()> async_handler;
    std::queue<async_handler> waiters_;

public:
    async_condition_variable(boost::asio::io_service& service) : service_(service)
    {
    }

    void async_wait(async_handler handler)
    {
        waiters_.push(handler);
    }

    void notify_one()
    {
        service_.post(waiters_.front());
        waiters_.pop();
    }

    void notify_all()
    {
        while (!waiters_.empty()) {
            notify_one();
        }
    }
};
```

Basically, each consumer would call `async_condition_variable::wait(...)`. Then, a producer would eventually call `async_condition_variable::notify_one()` or `async_condition_variable::notify_all()`. Each consumer's handle would be called, and would either act on the condition or call `async_condition_variable::wait(...)` again. Is this feasible or am I being crazy here? What kind of locking (mutexes) should be performed, given the fact that this would be run on a thread pool?

P.S.: Yes, this is more a RFC (Request for Comments) than a question :).

Comment: What's the use case? Do you need to do 1,000 different things when something happens? If so, this is totally the wrong way to go about it. (A pool of threads should be chewing on those 1,000 jobs that now need to be done.)

Comment: I have a (potentially large) set of clients that need to be able to receive tasks from a central server. A big part of these clients will be behind firewalls, so the idea is to keep the client-server connections always open. This 'async condition variable' is necessary for the server to dispatch a task to a given client when an external controller posts a new task.

Comment: i have the same issue. imagine implementing a server for APNS.. in APNS you don't get a response to your pushed message unless there is an error. Also you want to keep the socket open to push more messages thru it. So you have this pool of connections and they need to get next message to push from the pool. Naturally, you use condition_variable to do that. But waiting on a condition variable will suspend your connection thread and therefore you wont get the async_read to work unless you use wait with timeout to create a nearly busy-spin situation which sucks.

Comment: and here is my result so far (works fine): https://github.com/godexsoft/push_service/blob/master/src/push/detail/async_condition_variable.hpp

Comment: boost::asio::deadline_timer can do same thing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005258/why-does-boost-asio-not-support-an-event-based-interface-for-example-something

Answer (score 3):

Have a list of things that need to be done when an event occurs. Have a function to add something to that list and a function to remove something from that list. Then, when the event occurs, have a pool of threads work on the list of jobs that now need to be done. You don't need threads specifically waiting for the event.

Comment: And how would the function that removes something from the list be called? Please note that I'm using boost::asio with a thread pool, but the number of threads on the pool might as well be one.

Comment: @brunonery: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but the function would be a member function of the class that handles the event. It would acquire the lock that protects the list and then remove the item from the list. (The list could be a map or array, depending on how you want to do it. When you add an entry on the list, you could get back a "handle" to use to remove it. There are other ways.) Alternatively, the list could be a list of weak pointers, so just destroying the notification object would be sufficient. (On each notification, remove all dead pointers.)

Answer (score 1):

Boost::asio can be kind of hard to wrap your head around.  At least, I have difficult time doing it.

You don't need to have the threads wait on anything.  They do that on their own when they don't have any work to do.  The examples that seemed to look like what you wanted to do had work posted to the io_service for each item.

The following code was inspired from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754695/boost-asio-async-write-how-to-not-interleaving-async-write-calls#7756894).  It actually open my eyes to how you could use it do a lot of things.

I'm sure this isn't perfect, but I think it gives the general idea.  I hope this helps.

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
class ServerProcessor
{
protected:
    void handleWork1(WorkObject1* work)
    {
        //The code to do task 1 goes in here
    }
    void handleWork2(WorkObject2* work)
    {
        //The code to do task 2 goes in here
    }

    boost::thread_group worker_threads_;

    boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
    //This is used to keep io_service from running out of work and exiting to soon.
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> work_;


public:
    void start(int numberOfThreads)
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> myWork(new boost::asio::io_service::work(io_service_));
        work_=myWork;

        for (int x=0; x < numberOfThreads; ++x)
            worker_threads_.create_thread( boost::bind( &ServerProcessor::threadAction, this ) );

    }

    void doWork1(WorkObject1* work)
    {
        io_service_.post(boost::bind(&ServerProcessor::handleWork1, this, work));
    }

    void doWork2(WorkObject2* work)
    {
        io_service_.post(boost::bind(&ServerProcessor::handleWork2, this, work));
    }


    void threadAction()
    {
        io_service_.run();
    }

    void stop()
    {
        work_.reset();
        io_service_.stop();
        worker_threads_.join_all();
    }

};

int main()
{
    ServerProcessor s;

    std::string input;
    std::cout<<"Press f to stop"<<std::endl;

    s.start(8);

    std::cin>>input;

    s.stop();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You realize you're answering (an unanswered) question from four months ago, right? And that I have the code, but was asking for comments on the feasibility? Anyway, thanks for trying :)

Comment: @brunonery I did realize the question was from way back.  But, there was no accepted answer.  So I was trying to help.
As far as the code, it looked a lot different from how I've seen asio consumers being done.  So I tried to provide an example on how to do it with what is provided.  You don't actually need condition variables to do what you are trying to do.  I don't think asio was developed to be used that way.

Answer (score 0):

How about using boost::signals2?

It is a thread safe spinoff of boost::signals that lets your clients subscribe a callback to a signal to be emitted.

Then, when the signal is emitted asynchronously in an io_service dispatched job all the registered callbacks will be executed (on the same thread that emitted the signal).