# does boost::strand producer/consumer make sense?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, producer-consumer

In [this blog post (2010)](https://zhaowuluo.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/multithreading-boostasio/), someone is trying to solve the producer/consumer problem using Boost::strand facility. I have the feeling that he missed the point and that his program never runs simultaneously some producer and some consumer, but I'm not that expert of boost library to get confident about it.

- He's got only one strand, on which both `producer()` and `consumer()` calls are dispatched by some timers;
- He's got two thread, both invoking `io_service::run()`

Yet, one strand only with the guarantee that "none of those handlers will execute concurrently" also means that we'll be *either* producing *or* at a time, while I'd say nothing should prevent a producer from producing unit U+t while consumer uses unit U, right ?

```
   void producer_consumer::producer() {
     if ( count_ < num)   {
       ++count_;
       intvec_.push_back(count_);
       std::cout << count_ < " pushed back into integer vector." << std::endl;
       timer1_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(
           boost::bind(&producer_consumer::producer, this))); // loops back
       timer2_.async_wait(strand_.wrap(
           boost::bind(&producer_consumer::consumer, this))); // start consumer
     }
   }
```

Or am I missing the fact that there would be some `File::async_read()` accepting a strand-wrapped-"produce" function as completion callback and a similar Socket::ready-to-write-again that would explain that his proposal make sense as long as "producer()" and "consumer()" are actually the monitor-protected parts that interface with the shared buffer ?

Comment: The impression I got from the blog that the author suggests using Boost.Asio's `strand` for synchronization in preference to other synchronization constructs whenever possible, and provided a simplified example to demonstrate using `strand`.  Personally, I disagree with the thesis, as I prefer using `strand` _when_ it makes sense, not "_whenever possible_", and found the supporting evidence lacking, as the consequences are the result of multithreading, and not the synchronization mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code tends to focus much more on demonstrating `strand` as a synchronization mechanism, rather than providing a solution for the [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

For a motivational case of using `strand` to solve a producer-consumer problem, consider a GUI based chat client using TCP.  The GUI can produce multiple messages, trying to send a message before the previous message has been written to the connection.  Meanwhile, the application needs to consume and write each message to the TCP connection while preserving the messages, resulting in no interleaving data.  Composed operations, such as [`async_write`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html), requires that the stream perform no other write operations until the composed operation completes.  To account for these behaviors:

- A queue can buffer chat messages.
- The GUI can post an operation into `strand` that will:

  - Add the chat message to the queue.
  - Conditionally start the consumer.
- The consumer is an asynchronous call-chain that reads from the queue and writes to the socket within the `strand`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7756894/1053968) answer for an implementation.

Comment: By "conditionally start the consumer", I guess you imply the existence of some wake_thread_now() call that wouldn't prevent the thread to go to sleep later if awake right now.

Comment: meanwhile, it seems to me that if we have the queue, it solves the prod/cons problem you presented by its mere presence (unless pushing to the queue might block the GUI thread).

Comment: @sylvainulg: Conditionally starting is intentionally vague.  It could be some `wake_thread_now()`, but it could also be starting an asynchronous chain, as shown in the linked answer (`write()` -> `writeHandler()` chain).  With how `strand` works, it is more likely that the GUI creates an operation to push into the queue and immediately returns, rather than directly push into the queue where it may block.