# Boost Asio - Message content transmitted wrong

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-asio

I am building a client server communication. The server sends Header+Data (using async_write and a seperate IO Thread), Client receives Header of fixed size and knows how much data it has to read.

The Problem: Sometimes the client receives wrong data. It seems like the server sends the wrong data.

```
void Session::do_write(std::shared_ptr<DataItem> data)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(doWrite_mutex);

    std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
    buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(&data->length, sizeof(uint32_t)));
    buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(&data->callbackID, sizeof(uint8_t)));
    buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(&data->isString, sizeof(bool)));
    //Get the data to send into the buffer and make sure the given shared ptr to the data item keeps living until this function is finished.
    buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(data->getData(), data->length));

    boost::asio::async_write(*socket_, buffers, boost::bind(&Session::onSend, this, data, _1,_2));
}

    void Session::onSend(std::shared_ptr<DataItem> data,const boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
{ //Some logging, nothing special here 
}
```

The data item is a polymorphic class to handle different kinds of data (vectors, strings,...). The `getData()` method returns a `const void*` to the actual data (e.g. `myData->data()` in case of vector). The data is stored as a `shared_ptr` inside the DataItem (to keep it from being destroyed).

In most cases the data is transmitted correctly.

I don't know where to debug or what I am doing wrong.

Comment: " It seems like the server sends the wrong data." you should verify that.

Comment: I verified in `onSend` that the data in `data` is still correct, as expected.

Comment: I was more thinking, like, on the wire.

Comment: Since it is quite big binary data, it is hard to do so.

Comment: Do you ensure that `do_write` is not called until `onSend` gets invoked?

Comment: No, I don't, but since I am not using any global variable in there, this should be no problem?!

Comment: @Till: If the program does not ensure that the stream performs no other write operations until the previous [`async_write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html)'s completion handler has been invoked, then the program fails to meet a requirement that can result in interwoven data.  Does the client receive the expected data when using the synchronous [`write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write/overload1.html)?

Comment: @TannerSansbury You helped a lot! The program does work as expected when using `write` instead of `async_write`. 

I thought that the IO Service keeps track of multiple async_writes. Is there any elegant way to overcome this issue, since I write to different sockets in different classes, all using the same IO-Thread.

Comment: Boost Asio `strand`s come to mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking a write operation on a stream that has an outstanding `async_write()` operation fails to meet a requirement of `async_write()`, which can result in interwoven data.  Additionally, if multiple threads are servicing the `io_service` event loop or `Session::do_write()` is invoked from a thread that is not processing the event loop, then the use of a mutex will fail to meet the thread safety requirement of the stream.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7756894/1053968) demonstrates using a queue to serialize multiple `async_write()` operations,  and processing the queue with an asynchronous call chain within a [`strand`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__strand.html),  fulfilling both the requirements of `async_write()` and the stream's thread safety.

For further details, the [`async_write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) function is a composed operations, resulting in zero or more calls to the stream's [`async_write_some()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_write_some.html) function.  Therefore, if the program does not ensure that the stream performs no other write operations until the outstanding operation completes, the intermediate write operations can be mixed between other write operations, resulting in interwoven data.  Furthermore, these intermediate operations invoke `async_write_some()` on the stream without having acquired `doWrite_mutex`, potentially violating the thread safety requirement for the stream.  For more information about composed operations and `strand` usage, consider reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/1053968).