# How to stop boost::asio async reads from getting mixed up?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am using `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` to receive data. I need an interface which allows me to specify a buffer and call a completion handler once this buffer is filled asynchronously.

When reading from sockets, we can use the [`async_read_some`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) method.
However, the `async_read_some`  method may read less than the requested number of bytes, so it must call itself with the rest of the buffer if this happens. Here is my current approach:

```
template<typename CompletionHandler>
void read(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* sock, char* target, size_t size, CompletionHandler completionHandler){

   struct ReadHandler {
      boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* sock;
      char* target;
      size_t size;
      CompletionHandler completionHandler;

      ReadHandler(ip::tcp::socket* sock, char* target, size_t size, CompletionHandler completionHandler)
      : sock(sock),target(target),size(size),completionHandler(completionHandler){}
      // either request the remaining bytes or call the completion handler
      void operator()(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred){
         if(error){
            return;
         }

        if(bytes_transferred  < size){
           // Read incomplete
           char* newTarg =target+bytes_transferred;
           size_t newSize = size-bytes_transferred;
           sock->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(newTarg, newSize), ReadHandler(sock,newTarg,newSize,completionHandler));
           return;
        } else {
           // Read complete, call handler
           completionHandler();
        }
      }
   };

   // start first read
   sock->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(target, size), ReadHandler(this,target,size,completionHandler));
}
```

So basically, we call `async_read_some` until the whole buffer is filled, then we call the completion handler. So far so good. However, I think that things get mixed up once I call this method more than once before the first call finishes a receive:

```
void thisMayFail(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* sock){
   char* buffer1 = new char[128];
   char* buffer2 = new char[128];
   read(sock, buffer1, 128,[](){std::cout << "Buffer 1 filled";});
   read(sock, buffer2, 128,[](){std::cout << "Buffer 2 filled";});
}
```

of course, the first 128 received bytes should go into the first buffer and the second 128 should go into the second. But in my understanding, it may be the case that this does not happen here:

Suppose the first `async_read_some` returns only 70 bytes, then it would issue a second `async_read_some` with the remaining 58 bytes. However, this read will be queued behind the second 128 byte read(!), so the first buffer will receive the first 70 bytes, the next 128 will go into the second buffer and the final 50 go into the first. **I.e., in this case the second buffer would even be filled before the first is filled completely.** This may not happen.

How to solve this? I know there is the [`async_read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) method, but its documentation says it is simply implemented by calling `async_read_some` multiple times, so it is basically the same as my `read` implementation and will not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't have two asynchronous read operations active at the same time: that's undefined behaviour.

You can

- use the free function `async_read_until` or `async_read` functions, which already have the higher-level semantics and *loop* callling the socket's `async_read_some` until a condition is matched or the buffer is full.
- use asynchronous operation chaining to sequence the next async read after the first. In short, you initiate the second `boost::asio::async_read*` call in the *completion handler* of the first.

  Note:

  - Gives you the opportunity to act on transport errors first too.
  - together the free function interface will both raise the abstraction level of the code ***and*** solve the problem (the problem was initiating two simultaneous read operations)
- use a strand in case you run multiple IO service threads; See [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042)

Comment: 'You simply can't have two asynchronous read operations active at the same time: that's undefined behaviour' - I don't dispute that, but FFS why?  One of the advantages that AIO can have, (eg. Win IOCP), is that the kernel /driver will always have a buffer to shove data into, ie. there can be more than one outstanding IO request per socket:(

Comment: @MartinJames It's not strange. You can logically queue these operations without much effort at all. And if you want really high-level support see e.g. [scatter/gather IO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html#boost_asio.reference.buffer.buffers_and_scatter_gather_i_o)

Comment: Unfortunately, is seems that a full buffer will necessitate a trip to userspace and back again before I/O can continue:(

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah. I doubt there are portable means to implement this better. And perhaps the "asio-like" standards proposal fixes it (I don't watch it closely). Fingers crossed

Comment: @sehe: So I *can* queue the free `async_read` calls? First you say it is impossible, then you say I can do it. So will just calling `async_read` every time do the job?

Comment: Use the completion handler, strands or both. You can always explicitly queue requests. Which approach fits bets depends on your application, I don't think I can make that call given the info I have

Comment: @sehe: I am purely single threaded. Will simply calling: 
   `async_read(sock, buffer1, 128,[](){std::cout << "Buffer 1 filled";});`
   `async_read(sock, buffer2, 128,[](){std::cout << "Buffer 2 filled";});`  do the job? Or do I still need to queue the requests myself?

Comment: @gexicide You will not be ok. This [excellent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386012/boost-asio-message-content-transmitted-wrong/21397386#21397386) highlights the problems and links some typical solutions (having a small queue yourself is not hard to do). If you want to read more, I learned a lot from thiis [mailing list thread](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Multiple-async-operations-on-a-socket-td2579621.html) once