# What to do when asio::async_write doesn't call the handler?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have the following two member functions in a class. The _mtxWrite is a mutex object I use to make the write function thread safe. During heavy load, sometimes the writeHandler doesn't get called. Then _mtxWrite doesn't get released, resulting in a deadlock. What is the best way detect the situation and resolve the deadlock?

```
template <class TSession>
void write(boost::shared_ptr<TSession> pSession, 
    boost::shared_ptr<CInProtocolBase> pMessage)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char>* pData = new std::vector<unsigned char>;
    pMessage->serialize(*pData); 

    _mtxWrite.lock();
    boost::asio::async_write(_socket,boost::asio::buffer(&pData->at(0), 
        pData->size()),
        boost::bind(&this_type::writeHandler<TSession>,
        shared_from_this(),pSession,pData,boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

template <class TSession>
void writeHandler(boost::shared_ptr<TSession> pSession, 
    std::vector<unsigned char>* pData,const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    delete pData;
    _mtxWrite.unlock();

    if(ec)
    {
        _socket.get_io_service().post(boost::bind(&TSession::errorHandler,
            pSession,ec));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does your `writeHandler()` not have a `bytes_transferred` argument? And what is the exact type of `_mtxWrite`? If it's a recursive mutex then a call in the same thread will sail through that `lock()` and post an overlapping (and disallowed) `async_write()`. If it's not a recursive mutex then a call in the same thread will throw an exception if the lock was already acquired.

Comment: Enabling [handler tracking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/handler_tracking.html) may provide some insight into what is occurring.

Comment: @rhashimoto: It is boost::mutex,  not recursive. I am not using bytes_transferred for now, loss of a message is ok, but not deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is locking a mutex where `async_write()` is called and unlocking it in the handler. If these operations happen in different threads then this will violate the [`unlock()` preconditions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_concepts.basic_lockable.unlock) (the current thread owns the mutex). This may be causing your deadlock. In general, separated locking and unlocking is usually an indication of suboptimal design.

A better way of handling asynchronous writes would be to use a queue. The logic would look something like:

Write function:

- Lock mutex.
- Push buffer onto queue.
- If queue contains exactly one element, call `async_write` on the front element.
- Unlock mutex (ideally via a `scoped_lock` falling out of scope).

Write handler:

- Lock mutex.
- Pop buffer from queue (and free it).
- If the queue is not empty, call `async_write` on the front element.
- Unlock mutex (ideally via a `scoped_lock` falling out of scope).

With this approach locking is localized and there is no opportunity for deadlock. @TannerSansbury's pointer in the comments to using a strand for synchronization instead of a mutex will work similarly - it implicitly provides exclusion for any function run in the strand.

I've never had a case of a write handler not being called that wasn't eventually determined to be my own bug, but you can use a [boost::asio::deadline_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html) to watch for this by setting the timer when you call `async_write()` and canceling it in the write handler.

Comment: An example of an asynchronous queuing write chain synchronized with a `strand` is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7756894/1053968).

Comment: Yes, I am unlocking in a different thread. Didn't realise that would be a problem.

Comment: @SharathKShetty Mutex locking and unlocking is generally required to take place on the same thread. Your original code looks more like how a semaphore would be used - perhaps you're more familiar with that synchronization primitive. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62814/difference-between-binary-semaphore-and-mutex) might help to explain the difference.

Comment: I am not new to threading/mutexes, but relatively new to boost. Since this code worked most of the time, I thought it was okay. I think the io_service was reusing the same worker thread for the handler, so it worked most of the time, hence I didn't think about it. But when different thread was used, it went kaput. So the handler must have been called, but from a different worker thread. Is that a good explanation for what must have happened?

Comment: @SharathKShetty I'd say it's a conceivable explanation (and the only one I currently see) - I don't think you mention your OS and I wouldn't know the implementation of `boost::mutex` well enough anyway to say for sure. It's something that needed to be fixed, in any case. You also should put the `bytes_transferred` argument in your handler and placeholder in your handler binding.

Comment: I implemented the code as suggested in your answer, and it works beautifully. Thanks a lot. Regarding the bytes_transferred parameter, I added it. But I am not sure what is the right thing to do if the bytes_transferred value doesn't match the bytes I tried to write. Retry writing the remaining bytes? How common or rare is this situation?

Comment: For `async_write()`, `bytes_transferred` will [either be the total amount of data or an error will be set](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html). There can be no partial transfer without an error condition. The handler has that argument because it is a general form also used by other write functions that can have partial transfers, like `basic_stream_socket::async_write_some()`.