# Do I need to use a boost::strand in this server model?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I've been coding this server for quite some time now. I am calling io_service::run from more than 1 thread, but I am not sure if I ned to use strand here. Since I am never calling async_read more than once. Though it is possible that I call async_write more than once if other connections need to send something to others. This is the code I have so far

```
void Session::RecvPacket()
{
    boost::asio::async_read(m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(m_recv_buffer, len),
        boost::bind(&Session::OnRead, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

}

void Session::OnRead(const boost::system::error_code &e, size_t packet_length, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (e || bytes_transferred != packet_length)
    {
        if (e == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
            return;

        Stop();
        return;
    }

    // do something and most likely send a packet back

    RecvPacket();
}
void Session::SendPacket(packet &p)
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(send_mut);

    dword len = p.Lenght(); 

    m_crypt->makeheader(p.GetRaw().get(), static_cast<word>(len - 4));
    m_crypt->encrypt(p.GetRaw().get() + 4, len - 4);

    boost::asio::async_write(m_socket, boost::asio::buffer(p.GetRaw().get(), len),
        boost::bind(&Session::OnPacketSend, this, len, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, p.GetRaw()));
}
```

I am not sure wheter this is threadsafe or not. If only the send part is not threadsafe since I can send more than 1 packet at once (which is going to happen) should I only use a strand there?

Gz

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need a `strand`.

As noted in the [`tcp::socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html#boost_asio.reference.ip__tcp.socket.thread_safety) documentation, concurrent calls on the same socket (i.e. shared object) is not thread safe.  However, it is safe to have multiple asynchronous operations pending on an object.  Thus, this is safe:

```
 thread_1                             | thread_2
--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
socket.async_receive(...);            |
socket.async_write_some(...);         |
```

and this is safe:

```
 thread_1                             | thread_2
--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
socket.async_receive(...);            |
                                      | socket.async_write_some(...);
```

but this is specified as not being safe:

```
 thread_1                             | thread_2
--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
socket.async_receive(...);            | socket.async_write_some(...);
                                      |
```

Furthermore, the `send_mut` mutex in `Session::SendPacket()` provides no real safety to `m_socket`.  The [`boost::asio::async_write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) operation is a *composed operation*, made up of zero or more call's to the `m_socket.async_write_some()` function.  Due to the lifespan of the lock and the behavior of asynchronous operations, the lock does not guarantee that the mutex will be held during any or all of the `async_write_some()` operations.

For more details on thread safety and strands, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801042/1053968) answer.

---

Also, be aware that once an `async_write()` operation has been initiated on a stream, the program must ensure that no other write occurs on the stream until the initial operation's completion handler has been invoked:

> The program must ensure that the stream performs no other write operations (such as `async_write`, the stream's `async_write_some` function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until this operation completes.

If multiple writes need to be performed, then consider queuing up the writes, as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7756894/1053968) answer.  This type of solution may also make managing the lifespan of the `packet` object's underlying buffer easier, as the queue will own a copy of the data, meeting the `async_write()` operation's requirement that the buffer's underlying memory blocks remain valid until the completion handler is called.